# Redefinition error using namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
// main.cpp
const double MAX = 3.5;

namespace ns
{
   const int MAX = 3;
}

int main()
{
}
```

will this cause redefinition error?

I'm referring to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which says in the Remarks section that this is an error.

Update: I think I may miss one important statement when copying around the code.

```
using ns::MAX;
```

Comment: Just out of interest, can you supply a link to the MSDN page?

Comment: It is in the Remarks.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly - thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - I don't see how that code would cause a redefinition error.

And in fact, you can [compile it and see for yourself](http://ideone.com/7qYY4).

---

**EDIT:** Following up now that you've supplied the link to the MSDN page you mentioned...

That MSDN page is talking about name clashes in the context of a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> If a local variable has the same name as a namespace variable, the
>   namespace variable is hidden. It is an error to have a namespace
>   variable with the same name as a global variable.

[Here's an example](http://ideone.com/4uNPB) of a local variable hiding a namespace variable that's been brought into scope by a `using` directive:

```
namespace ns
{
   const int MAX = 3;
}

using namespace ns;

int main()
{
   int MAX = 4; // local
   int test = MAX;   // test is 4, because the local variable is used 
                     // as the namespace variable is hidden
}
```

The inclusion of the `using` directive brings all of the names declared within the `ns` namespace into scope. However, when I assign the value of `MAX` to `test`, it's the local variable `MAX` that is used in the assignment because the namespace variable `MAX` is hidden. The local variable takes precedence and hides the namespace variable.

Now here's an example of a clash between a namespace variable and a global variable. 
Consider this amended piece of code (and you can see it compile [here](http://ideone.com/QH5rG)):

```
const double MAX = 3.5;

namespace ns
{
   const int MAX = 3;
}

using namespace ns;

int main()
{
   int test = MAX;
}
```

Again, the `using` directive brings `ns:MAX` into scope, and the global variable `MAX` is also in scope.

When I go to use the variable called `MAX` in `main()`, the compiler reports an error because the name `MAX` is now ambiguous: it has no way of knowing which `MAX` we are referring to, as there are two non-local `MAX`s to choose from: neither has any precedence.

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:13: error: reference to ‘MAX’ is ambiguous
prog.cpp:2: error: candidates are: const double MAX
prog.cpp:6: error:                 const int ns::MAX
prog.cpp:13: error: reference to ‘MAX’ is ambiguous
prog.cpp:2: error: candidates are: const double MAX
prog.cpp:6: error:                 const int ns::MAX
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Initially, I was expecting a compilation error before using it and compiler would complain at using namespace ns;, but I didn't get it. I was puzzled there.

Answer (score 2):

They wouldn't because one is in file scope and the other in namespace scope.